# Google Apps Script (GAS) Using urlfetchapp with username and password

Tags: google-apps-script

I am not a coder by nature and am self taught in GAS (only code I have used). I work for City College Norwich and I would like to create a script that automatically logs me in to their website so I can fetch timetable data and put it into a spreadsheet.

After doing some research I have given up trying to figure it out so I am asking for help.

I have tried this:

```
function getTimetables() {
 var url = "https://ccn.ac.uk/user/";
   var options = {
      "method": "post",
      "payload": {
      "user-login" : "username",
      "edit-pass" : "password",
      "BUTTON_Submit" : "Log In",
      },
      "testcookie": 1,
      "followRedirects": false
   };
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
   if ( response.getResponseCode() == 200 ) {
     // Incorrect user/pass combo
     Logger.log('Incorrect user/pass combo')
   } else if ( response.getResponseCode() == 302 ) {
     // Logged-in
     var headers = response.getAllHeaders();
     if ( typeof headers['Set-Cookie'] !== 'undefined' ) {
        // Make sure that we are working with an array of cookies
        var cookies = typeof headers['Set-Cookie'] == 'string' ? [ headers['Set-Cookie'] ] : headers['Set-Cookie'];
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
           // We only need the cookie's value - it might have path, expiry time, etc here
           cookies[i] = cookies[i].split( ';' )[0];  
        };

        url = "https://mytimetable.ccn.ac.uk/timetable.aspx?week=30&room=C5A";
        options = {
            "method": "get",
            // Set the cookies so that we appear logged-in
            "headers": {
               "Cookie": cookies.join(';') 
            }
        } 
     }
   }
}
```

Which return "Incorrect user/pass combo".

And I have tried this:

```
function getTimetablev2() {
var site = "https://ccn.ac.uk/user"
var USERNAME = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('username');
var PASSWORD = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('password');

var url = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(site);

  var headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD)
  };

var params

 = {
    "method":"GET",
    "headers":headers
  };

var response = 

UrlFetchApp.fetch(site, params); 
  Logger.log(response.getResponseCode())
}
```

Which return code 200 - failed to log in.

If anyone can solve this for me I would be forever in your debt as it would save me loads of time. I have created a practical booking system where each teacher has their own spreadsheet with their timetable on and all bookings go to a master spreadsheet us technicians use. If I could automate generating their timetables it would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how a valid HTTP POST to https://ccn.ac.uk/user/ looks, it's hard to answer your question. So...

Using [hurl.it](http://hurl.it) and your payload provided in the first code snippet... it doesn't look like this is a valid POST.

Using [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) and inputing dummy data into the form you are able to look at how the POST is done correctly.

[image: valid post request]

These are the parameters you should use in your request body.

---

Your second code snippet is not very likely to work if this site doesn't natively support authentication other than using this form.